# I have installed Apache Airflow 2.0 but DAGs are not visible

Tags: airflow

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/get-started-airflow-2) on getting Airflow v2 set up. This set up come with an example DAG unfortunately they are not visible on my webserver UI dags page.

I have tried to install again but did not help, I have used `astro start`/ `astro stop` also without any success

My Dockerfile has only one line `FROM quay.io/astronomer/ap-airflow:latest-onbuild`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your dockerfile please

Comment: @kaxil Thank you when I run cat Dockerfile I only get one line  `FROM quay.io/astronomer/ap-airflow:latest-onbuild`